# How to increase Session Timeout in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, timeout

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="20" mode="InProc"/>
  </system.web>
```

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Is it in the <configuration>? No, nothing else. Be aware, that those are minutes.

Comment: yeah in web.config file

Answer (score 4):

That should be alright but do also check if you are overriding that value in your code behind somewhere by saying below. Probably in the `Global.asax` file under `Session_Start()`

```
Session.Timeout = "40";
```

Comment: Does this override the IIS timeout as well? If not, he's going to need to change that too.

Comment: @Kramb, AFAIK, setting this in cofig or code behind is same as setting in IIS

Comment: 40 minutes or 40 second.?

Comment: @MehulJariwala, that's in minute and not seconds

Comment: @MehulJariwala, do you have session timeout set in IIS as well? check once

Comment: plz tell me how to set session timeout in IIS

Comment: @MehulJariwala, you should have search in Google ... but anyways check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx